# Редирект на существующие страницы от 403

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

Вопросы сугубо, а так можно сделать, а как?
Подключенные спринги 3.1.2.RELEASE
Доступ ко всем страницам `<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>`
Пользователи:

```
<user name="1" password="1" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
<user name="2" password="2" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_LOCAL_ADMIN"/>
<user name="3" password="3" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_LOCAL_ADMIN, ROLE_ADMIN"/>
```

И контроллер:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/second")
public ModelAndView indexPage(Principal user) {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("secondPage");

    modelAndView.addObject("methodMessage", testMsg.Message(user));

    return modelAndView;
}
```

`testMsg.Message(user)` защищен `@Secured(value = "ROLE_ADMIN")`
Авторизуюсь как `ROLE_USER`, пытаюсь зайти на страницы где будет отработан защищенный метод и перенаправляюсь на страницу авторизации:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/login</location>
</error-page>
```

Можно ли эту ситуацию обработать как ни будь через контроллер?
Что бы я *мог вывести сообщение на странице авторизации*: `"Вам нужно повысить права для доступа к ХХХХХХ странице"`. А потом, *после авторизации редирект на ту страницу куда хотел попасть*, ибо сейчас кидает на **мой_сайт/**.

**UPD 1.** Сообщения после редиректа на странице `login` можно делать с помощью `RedirectAttributes`. Осталось понять как прикрутить всё остальное.

Comment: Почему такую древнюю версию Спринга используете?

Comment: @iksuy Потому что только её удалось сконфигурировать (security). Ну, это же для изучения, разницы наверное нет какую изучать для общего понимания. Потом буду пытаться на свежей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В спринге есть [AccessDeniedHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/AccessDeniedHandler.html), с помощью которого можете делать всё, что захотите:

```
@Component
public class CustomAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request,
                   HttpServletResponse response,
                   AccessDeniedException e) throws IOException,
                                                   ServletException {

        //...some code
        // можете делать все, что захотите, например
        response.sendRedirect("/403");
        //...some code

}
```